# Tengo una lista la cual quiero que se ponga del tamaña de la ventana estoy programando en C# WPF

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

osea quiero poner que esa datagrip se ponga del tamaño de la ventana cuando se mueve la ventana  y se ponga en pantalla completa.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: anclala a los bordes (anchor) es una propiedad del control

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: quiero que la lista crezca junto con la ventana